# Inkcanvas with Citrix Receiver Mobility

Tags: citrix, inkcanvas

We currently deploy a CMS type application through the Citrix Environment and i have added an electronic signature feature which I wrote using an WPF Inkcanvas.  This part of our application works well when using the pen mouse through a desktop version of the receiver, but very poorly when accessing it through a tablet, Ipad or Droid.  When you go to try to scribble you signature you either to hold your finger to initiate the left-click hold, this is longer of droid than Ipad.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  I want it to work just like Square signing feature a just draw by touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here. The simplest is to tell admins to set the Application Description to the following when publishing the application:

keywords:mobile

On the mobile receivers (iOS and Android) this does a few things, the useful one for you is it puts them into a different input mode where the receiver does less gesture detection and pushes through events more directly.

You can perform more finer grained control of the input mode using the Mobility SDK for Windows Apps. You can probably get away without the added complexity of using the SDK and just use the extra keywords in the publishing step. But if you're interested there are multiple language bindings for the SDK, including .NET. The main SDK link is here:

http://www.citrix.com/mobilitysdk/

The specific class you use to set the input mode with the .NET binding is here (see BeginSetTouchInputMode):

http://www.citrix.com/mobilitysdk/docs/cmp.net/index.html

Finally the last option is to get your customers using the latest XenDesktop 7 using Windows Server 2012. This is the latest release and it supports touch remoting, so the receiver will not perform any gesture translation that delays user input. Instead it will pass all the touch events directly up to the server for processing. The iOS receiver has implemented touch remoting, however I'm not sure if it's been added to the Android receiver yet.

So the tl;dr is use "keywords:mobile", and then when your customers eventually upgrade to XenDesktop 7 this should become a non-issue.